# Workflow with two receive activities and correlation

Tags: workflow-foundation-4

I've a workflow that has two receive activities in a pick activity. Whenever I get a request in the first request activity the workflow has to create a new instance while if the second receive activity get requests it should not create a new instance instead the messages should be routed to the already running instance (there should be an instance running already). How can I handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some blog posts about how to setup message correlation to do this. Check [here](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/04/28/workflow-receive-activity-and-message-correlation.aspx) for a good starting point.